# SQL: return row with maximum value per group

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I want to get the rows with the maximum values for each person. Using MySQL.

```
person       page       views
John         home       20
John         cart       15
John         search     43
James        home       32
James        about      41
Kim          cart       5
Kim          contact    3
```

Result

```
Person   Page
John     search
James    about
Kim      cart
```

One thought is to get the `MAX(views) GROUP BY PERSON`and then do `IF(a.views = b.max_views, page, 0)` but this seems like it would require 3 steps and there is probably an easier way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 Select * From table t
 where views =
     (Select Max(views) From table
      Where person = t.person)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery to get the result:

```
select t1.person, t1.page
from yt t1
inner join
(
  select max(views) maxview, person
  from yt
  group by person
) t2
  on t1.person = t2.person
  and t1.views = t2.maxview;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b89d/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select 
    * 
from 
   data d
where d.views =  ( select max(views) from data d2 where d2.person = d.person )
```

Comment: the `d2` alias is not needed

Comment: @CharlesBretana Yup, have got used to giving alias to queries ;)

Comment: the d2 is not an alias for a query, it is just an alias for the table `data` inside the subquery.  It is not needed because the query processor always looks for columns in all tables of the current query/subquery before it looks outside the current query.

Comment: right, in a bad habit of giving aliases of table names when not needed